# C++11 memory pool class - workaround for static_casting from void*?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want a class `P` that has a static `delete_all` member function, that will delete all dynamically allocated instances of type `P` or a type derived from `P`.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

struct P
{
    static unordered_set<P*> pool;

    static void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        void* p = ::operator new(size);
        pool.insert(static_cast<P*>(p));
        return p;
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        pool.erase(static_cast<P*>(p));
        ::operator delete(p);
    }

    static void delete_all()
    {
        while (!pool.empty())
            delete *(pool.begin());
    }

    virtual ~P() {}; // polymorphic
};

unordered_set<P*> P::pool;
```

An example usage is then like this:

```
struct D : P
{
    ...
};

int main()
{
    D d1;
    D* d2 = new D();
    D* d3 = new D();

    delete d2;

    P::delete_all(); // deletes d3, but not d1 or d2
}
```

The part I am concerned about is statically casting the `void*` pointer to `P*`.  I have a feeling that this will lead to undefined behaviour in some cases, for example when new is called on a derived class where the P base class subobject doesn't start at the beginning of the derived class.  The memory block doesn't know yet that it is of type derived class, so the `static_cast<P*>` from void will not give the correct location of the P subobject.

Am I correct that this is a problem?  How can I fix it?

Also, is there an additional problem with `P` that I am not aware of?

Comment: A technique I have seen involves tracking what is `new`ed in `operator new`, and doing the pooling in the constructor when we have a valid pointer: that pointer will be between the `void*` and the `void*+size_t`.  However, will your `new` be called in `new Derived`?

Comment: You can also use the `dynamic_cast<P *>(ptr)` construct. This will make sure you get the correct pointer, or will return NULL if the cast fail. However, this isn't free, as this cast is done at runtime.

Comment: @Yakk: _"However, will your new be called in new Derived?"_ I don't understand what you are asking.  Yes, a dynamically allocated object produced by `new Derived` should be added to the pool and deleted by `delete_all` if it hasn't been already.

Comment: @Xaqq: I don't think that will work because the memory block returned by `::operator new (bytes)` doesn't yet have the necessary type information in it to support a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @user1131467 Mmm, yeah you're probably right - can someone with more experience confirm ? However, your set could be a set of `void *` and the `dynamic_cast` would be done when `delete`ing your objects. Could that work for you?

Comment: @Xaqq: This moves the problem to the `delete` operation in `delete_all`.  It isn't clear if you call `delete p` where `p` is a `void*`, will it dynamically find the right subclass of `P` to delete (the right destructor), even given `P` is a polymorphic class.

Comment: @Xaqq: No, you cannot `dynamic_cast` an expression of type `void*` to any pointer type.  See 5.2.7.2

Comment: @user1131467 Woops, I totally forget about that. Thanks for the reminder. Sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: Do insert in the ctor, erase in the dtor, never use static cast on pointers unless you know the source's *dynamic* type.

Comment: @n.m.: The ctor and dtor are also called for non-dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: You can have a secondary set of raw memory *areas* (a pointer plus its allocated size). In the operator new, add the area to that set. In the constructor, check whether your object is inside of one of the areas. If yes, add it to the pool and remove the corresponding area. I think that's what Yakk proposes, in essence. This doesn't take care of array allocations (with `new[]`), those are extremely tricky to get right.

Comment: @n.m.: This also doesn't distinguish base class subobjects from member subobjects.  For example `struct D : P { P x; }`, how do I distinguish `D::x` from the base class `P`?

Comment: This is a tricky case. Normally the base-P constructor will run before the member-P one, and remove the area from the aux set. In case of MI this will be broken by `struct E{P p;}; struct D: E, P{}`. You can have fix this by splitting P in two classes, `class P: private virtual Pbase` and doing everything in Pbase.

Comment: Will this problem exist only if P is not the only root in your inheritance chain? If P is the only root, i.e., no class multiply-inherits P, this should work fine, correct?

Comment: @TripShock: it will probably work in practice but there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your static_casts are a problem, for the exact reason you describe.

Unless I'm missing something obvious, you don't need the whole operator new/operator delete dance. Just have P's constructor store `this` in the pool, and P's destructor remove it from the pool. This way, you always deal with honest P* pointers. Make sure to do this in all constructors (recall that the compiler would generate copy and move constructors if you don't provide or disable them explicitly).

Comment: he has an explicitly defined destructor, so move constructors won't be generated.